Construction of probability space for deterministic sequence
When encountering statements that sound probabilistic regarding deterministic sequences, I wonder if they can be given a true probabilistic sense.
For instance, consider 2 notions of "uniformly distributed"

(i) Weak, deterministic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence

(ii) Strong, probability: realization of iid uniform random variables over some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$.


I call the second strong because of statistics and ergodic theory, as it usually ensures the 1st.
From a "law of large number perspective", (i) ensures consistency of "empirical" averages, without requiring that the limit is actually defined as an expectation (over some probability space which I am trying to build).
My main question is:
Q0: "under what condition can or can't I build a probability space such that the deterministic numbers in (i) are identified to random variables in (ii), and (i) is actually consequence of some uniform law of large number, or ergodic theorem, in (ii)"
Main example
Recursion $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$ with $g(x) = 4 x (1-x)$.
$\{g(x)=x\} = \{0,x^*\}$ only has 2 (repulsive) fixed points. However it has fixed point in distribution, with density $f(x) = (  x (1-x) )^{-1/2}$. The image distribution of that law remains the same when applied $g$.
If I start from a $x_0$ not in the (countable) ancestors of $\{0,x^*\}$, I expect the sequence $x_n$ to converge to $f$ in some weak distributionnal sense.
Here, transition $g$ is deterministic. If it was random, I know how Markov Chain theory would ensure such convergence (under the good assumptions of Lyapounov stability, regular / topology properties, innovation with density and connected open support ...). This convergence would hold in a probabilistic sense (the one on which the random innovation lives).
This theory handles tons of technicalities (communication, mixing ...) that sound
could simplify in the deterministic case, so I expect strong results as well, but I don't know how to handle the deterministic case, because no such probability space is defined (yet?).
Q1: How do you prove convergence to $f$ in the weak sense (i) ? Is $f$ an attractive point in some distributional dual space (which is probably ensured by Lyapounov type condition in the case of random chains) ?
Q2: Can you build a probability space and prove a strong convergence (ii) ?
It sounds as trying to apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skorokhod%27s_representation_theorem, but maybe it's even simpler.
Q3: Was there ever such explicitly constructed probability space to represent deterministic sequences as random. I would be surprised none of Lebesgue, Carathéodory or Skorokhod tried.
Q4: Above, I focused on "marginal distribution" statement. Because the system is chaotic, I would also ask if $x_t$ becomes independent of $x_s$ when $t-s$ is large.
Since (i) defines a notion of marginal distribution, it probably implies a notion of independence (based on distribution of pairs),
which I also want to give a true probability meaning.
I feel there are similar questions, if not answers, in the fields of ergodic theory, pseudo-random number generation, real number theory (eg can uniformity of $\pi * n (mod 1)$ be obtained on an actual space ?)
Back to Q0
I expect some necessary conditions, in particular that the limit (i) is consistent with formulation (ii):

I feel the limit in (i) is only additive; not $\sigma-$additive.
How to define the tribe and probability so that the chaoticity in $x_n$ becomes independence or "mixing" in the probability space ?

Periodic or low-discrepancy sequences verify (i) but don't exhibit the usual convergence speed to their marginal - building the probability space will define which of these sequences have enough "independence" to be applied LLN or CLT. It could even be possible to recover these degenerated cases from the probability space with some probability for dependant sequence (eg weak dependence).
If I had to guess such a construction, here are some 2 cent ideas (I am trying to map point to function so that they can be treated as random variables):
a) Having $x_0$ random propagates to the entire sequence, but this is only a tribe, not a filtration. This cannot capture the mixing properties I am interested in.
b) $\mathbb{R}$ is already within functional space $2^\mathbb{N}$ (but can $\omega$ be just an index ?)
c) Map points to functions in Skohorod space (map each real x to the dirac cdf $1(y \le x)$ ?), because it is an example of the existence of such a space / strong convergence
(d) Or with reproducing kernel (which maps points to functions based on some scalar product)
e) Shuffle $x_n$ with random time change, so that the sequence now lives in a probability space (sounds it can't handle time series, only $i.i.d$ sequence).
The last one is inspired with an actual example of point/random-variable identification,  hashcode functions feeding an uniform argument : in some string space with concatenation +, points $"x"$ and $"y"$ are independent, being identified with $h("x" + u)$ and $h("y" + u)$ which are independent random variables when input u is uniform (this input $u$ provides the probability space).
Thank you !

I'm not convinced by the premise. What is a concrete example of a probabilistic statement about a deterministic sequence? The examples you alluded to do not appear probabilistic. If there's no randomness, there's no need to make probabilistic statements.

@msantama: tyvm for the feedback. I completely rewrote the question and give a precise example.

Maybe there are examples from statistical mechanics which can give you what you are looking for.  In stat mechanics,  you can have a deterministic system that is nonetheless modeled probabilistically.

Q2: Isn't that density estimation from a sequence?  There's years of research on that in the literature.  Also, there are cases where that's impossible: https://doi.org/10.1214/aop/1022855650.  Q3: A deterministic sequence generated by an invertible transformation is not probabilistic.  The output of a Bernoulli transformation $T$ is deterministic; it's the process $X_i=f\circ T^i$ that appears random for certain functions $f$ (i.e., simple functions on cylinder sets).

An interesting paper by Dorothy Maharam on how orbits from an e.m.p.t. determine that transformation: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1994229.
